# WP Query Get Posts by Comment Author ID and specific keyword?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a custom loop which gets the posts that author__in 1 has commented the specific keyword 'test' on and use that to build the recent posts list.

```
<?php $query_args = array('search' => 'test', 'author__in' => '1', 'post_status' => 'publish', ); $the_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $query_args );?> <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>


 <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

This query doesn't work, it gives me nothing, i guess ->have_posts does not exist for wp_comment_query?

How can i build a query using WP_query that lists the most recent posts with comment 'test' from author with id 1? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here.

First, the "search" parameter is actually only "s", not the full word. Here's that reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter

Second, the `author__in` param takes an array, like this: `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );` rather than a single integer or quoted digit. Here's that reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

I think you could get what you want by just changing your code slightly. One thing to note, I'm not sure if the search parameter does a keyword search in comments though, it might only search post content. Try this:

`$query_args = array('s' => 'test', 'author__in' => array(1), 'post_status' => 'publish', );`

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I think i solved it by changing the  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?> to if ( !empty( $comments ) ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {                          not exactly what i was looking for but it does pulll the comments and i can build the data from it